# Can't access function from header file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdafx.h

```
//head.h//
extern int sum(int,int);
```

```
//head.cpp//

#include "head.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
int sum(int x, int y)
{
return (x+y);
}
```

```
//mainfn.cpp//

#include "head.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include string
#include iostream
#include stdio.h
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using namespace System;

int main()
{
int x=10,y=2;
printf("value:  %d",sum(x,y));
Console::ReadLine();
return 0;
}
```

While buliding in Visual studio 2005, this vc++ project is giving following error:

```
error C3861: 'sum': identifier not found.
```

Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: What's in stdafx.h, and what are your precompiled header settings? Maybe you have something weird going on with precompiled headers since the posted code otherwise is fine.

Comment: actually when i start the new VC++ project in visual studio, this precompiled header file is always included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to place the inclusion of *head.h* **after** *stdafx.h*. When precompiled headers are enabled the compiler will ignore the contents of all includes that occur prior to (in this case) the inclusion of *stdafx.h* .

Comment: thnx chet.. thnx a lot for correcting the silly error. now its fine.

Comment: @durgesh t: If it's fine - you might want to accept this guy's answer

Answer (score 3):

Either remove stdafx.h from the project, and turn of precompiled headers.. or try moving head.h to be included *after* stdafx.h instead of before.